# Using SvcUtil.exe in WCF when router is in the middle

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, svcutil.exe

My service is consumed through a router. I’m trying to use SvcUtil.exe to create config and class file. When I point to the service itself endpoints the command would be something like this:

svcutil.exe http://'localhost':8080/MyService_endpoint

"Please don't mind the ' in the address"

With this command everything works and I have all my service methods (Contracts) in the client side.
Now my problem is when I try to use svcutil to create config and the class through router I use this command:

svcutil.exe http://'localhost':8080/MyRouter_endpoint

The files are created but none of the service methods are mentioned in the class file. 
My question is how can we use svcutil when router is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SvcUtil.exe` to create the proxy of the target WCF service and in the configuration you have to change the address to point to the router's address instead of the service one.

So you can still access the classes and interfaces of the service but only the communication happens through the router's address.